# Centos 8 LVM and partitions

Tags: centos, filesystems, lvm

anyone can help to decode this?
Two partitions with the same volume?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [LVM](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/ch-lvm) volume group called `cl` on top of two partitions (in LVM terminology two *physical volumes*) `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda4`. The `cl` volume group contains two logical volumes `root` and `swap`. The `swap` logical volume is fully allocated on the `sda3` physical volume and the `root` logical volume is partly allocated on the `sda3` physical volume and partly on the `sda4` physical volume -- if you look at the sizes it makes sense: sda4 is only 310 GiB and the `root` logical volume is 344 GiB so it wouldn't fit on just sda4.

If you are interested in more detailed view, you can use `pvdisplay -m` which shows what parts of which physical volume is actually used for which parts of the logical volumes:

```
  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 210600:
    Logical volume      /dev/fedora/home
    Logical extents     0 to 210600
  Physical extent 210601 to 228517:
    Logical volume      /dev/fedora/root
    Logical extents     0 to 17916
```

I have just one PV, but you can see that its first part is occupied by my `/home` LV and the second part by my `/` LV.